# How to Distribute a Digital Signage Tizen Studio App via URLauncher: Certification Requirements?

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, url-launcher, app-distribution

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I have developed an digital-signage application using Tizen Studio and am looking to distribute it through URLauncher. However, I'm uncertain about the process, particularly regarding any certification requirements. I would appreciate guidance on the following points:

Distribution Process: Could someone explain the steps involved in making my Tizen Studio app available for download through URLauncher? Are there specific configurations or settings within Tizen Studio that I need to be aware of?

Certification Requirements: Is there a certification process that my application needs to undergo before it can be distributed through URLauncher? If so, what does this process entail and what are the criteria for certification?

Best Practices: Are there any best practices or common pitfalls that I should be aware of when distributing an app in this manner?

Any insights, resources, or examples from those who have experience with Tizen Studio and URLauncher would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

My main goal is to ensure a smooth distribution process for my Tizen Studio app via URLauncher. Specifically, I am looking for:

Clear Step-by-Step Guidance: A detailed explanation of the steps required to make my app available through URLauncher. This includes any necessary configurations within Tizen Studio and the process of uploading or linking my app for download.

Understanding Certification Requirements: Comprehensive information on whether my app needs to undergo a certification process for distribution via URLauncher. If certification is required, I expect to learn about the procedures, criteria, and any documentation I need to prepare.

Practical Advice: Tips and best practices from experienced developers who have successfully distributed apps through URLauncher. Also, common pitfalls to avoid during this process would be highly beneficial.

By understanding these aspects, I aim to efficiently distribute my app while complying with all necessary guidelines and standards set by the Tizen platform.

Comment: I am not sure about URLauncher in Tizen. but, would you check this page for distribution process. https://developer.samsung.com/tv-seller-office/guides/overview.html